# Visualizing $A:=\left \{ \left(t,\frac{1}{t}\right) : \frac{1}{4} <t <4\right \}$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

let $(\mathbb{R}^2, |\cdot |_\infty )$ be a metric space. How can I visualize $A:=\left \{ \left(t,\frac{1}{t}\right) : \frac{1}{4} <t <4\right \}$?

I know that $|\cdot |_\infty$ looks like a square in the cartesian coordinate system. But what part of the square is $A$?

Comment: $(\mathbb{R}^2,|\cdot|_{\infty})$ is specific already, not just "a" metric space. Your set $A$ is defined in terms of the order on $\mathbb{R}$, so it has nothing to do with your choice of metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$. It simply is the graph of $f(x)=1/x$ on the interval $(\frac{1}{4},4)$. The only point at which it intersects the unit ball in the $\infty$-norm is the point $(1,1)$.

Comment: Isn't A just the graph of the function 1/t between 1/4 and 4?

Comment: I think what OP is asking is what is the shape of $|A|_\infty$ in the ball representation of the metric.

Comment: I'm having problems translating the original question. Does "Let $\mathbb{R}^2$ be given with $|\cdot |_\infty$" make sense?

Comment: Note that this is not really the question, I just want to visualize it to get a grasp of what I'm dealing with, to compute $A^\circ$, $\bar{A}$ etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A$ is nothing but a *subset* of $\mathbb{R}^2$, which is nothing but the *graph* of the function $f(t)=\frac{1}{t}$ on the open interval $\frac14<t<4$.

On the other hand, given $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ with
$$
|(x,y)|_{\infty}=\max\{|x|,|y|\}, 
$$
you could ask, how the following set looks like:
$$
S=\{|(x,y)|_\infty\mid (x,y)\in A\}.
$$
But note that 
$$
|(t,\frac1t)|_\infty=\frac1t, \quad t\in(\frac14,1);\\
|(t,\frac1t)|_\infty=t, \quad t\in[1,4).
$$
So the set $S$ can be visualized as the graph of the following piece-wise function:
$$
f(t)=\begin{cases}
\frac1t, &t\in(\frac14,1);\\
t, & t\in[1,4).
\end{cases}
$$

---

> I know that $|\cdot |_\infty$ looks like a square in the cartesian coordinate system. But what part of the square is $A$?

It is not that "$|\cdot |_\infty$ looks like a square", but that the *set*
$$
Q=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid |(x,y)|_\infty=1\}
$$
looks like a square.